# comparing and sorting array

Tags: python, list

From two unequal arrays, i need to compare & delete based on the last value of an array.

Example:

`m[0]` and `n[0]` are read form a text file & saved as a array, `[0]` - their column number in text file.

```
m[0] = [0.00, 1.15, 1.24, 1.35, 1.54, 2.32, 2.85, 3.10, 3.40, 3.80, 4.10, 4.21, 4.44]

n[0] = [0.00, 1.12, 1.34, 1.45, 2.54, 3.12, 3.57]
```

`n[0]` last value is `3.57`, it lies between `3.40` and `3.80  of m[0] so I need to print till 3.40 in`m[0]`

**Required output:**

```
p[0] = [0.00, 1.15, 1.24, 1.35, 1.54, 2.32, 2.85, 3.10, 3.40]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if both lists are ordered, you can do:

```
import bisect
m[0][:bisect.bisect(m[0],n[0][-1])]
```

Answer (score 6):

Some details are a little unclear, but this should do what you want:

```
p[0] = [x for x in m[0] if x < n[0][-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test this but here you go...

```
p = []
for item in m[0]:
    if (item < n[0][-1]):
        p.append(item)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: len(n) is completely unnecessary here.

Comment: @hop: There is so much that is unnecessary here. When you start teasing it apart, it becomes Ned Batchelder's one-liner.